# Projects using Indy don't compile after upgrade to 10.2 Tokyo

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-10.2-tokyo

After uninstalling Delphi 10 Seattle, removing all directories containing 'Embarcadero', then installing Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, my projects using Indy no longer compile:

```
Could not compile used unit 'IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders'
```

- Nothing changed in the projects' search path (these are only relative to the project)
- `Tools/Delphi Options/Library/Browsing path` contains `$(BDS)\source\Indy10\Protocol` (and *Core* and *System*), and `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.pas` is in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\source\Indy10\Protocols\`
- Adding `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` to the uses clause does not help (12 other Indy file names were added automatically because I used design time components)
- There is a TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL component on the form
- There is nothing relating to Indy in the `Tools/Delphi Options/Library/Library Path`
- `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.dcu` etc. are in the `c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\lib\win32\release\` folder
- The editor shows red wigglies under `IdSSLOpenSSL` in the Uses clause, with hint 'Cannot resolve unit name'
- There are no old id*.dcu files in unexpected places on the disk

I found two workarounds that I'm both not particularly happy with:

1. The Indy files are not part of the project; explicitly adding IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.pas to the project makes it compile again, but I'm not happy about that: `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.pas` now compiles in that source directory, leaving a .dcu file there.
   Besides, all the other Indy files are **not** part of the project.
2. Copying `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.pas` and `IdCompilerDefines.inc` to my projects' directory

Is there a better solution that I'm overlooking?

I am trying to create a small project to reproduce the issue, but so far this compiles???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

There were two projects involved, with some common files. Whichever one of the two I tried to build, I got the error.

The solution was to delete all .dcu files local to both projects.

Don't ask me why, but it seems there was some (order?)<sup>*</sup> dependency that building either one was unable to resolve.
After this, the order in which I build does not matter.

Note: *I was thinking about deleting my question because this is such a weird and unreproducable issue (a test program I was gradually complicating kept compiled without errors).
Instead I decided to self-answer; who knows who this may help in the future.*

<sup>* While trying, I even tried changing the order of the file names in the Uses statement, but that did not help.</sup>

Comment: I don't really see the point of retaining this question. You haven't got to the bottom of it. The detail in the question isn't sufficient to answer the question. If I were you I'd get rid of the whole lot.

Comment: Any reason why you (apparently) manually delete old .dcu files?  Why not just perform a "Clean"?

Comment: @J... What's a "Clean"?? The idea to delete them was just another wild idea after having tried many others.

Comment: @JanDoggen Right-click your project - there are options `Compile`, `Build`, `Clean`.  `Compile` compiles the .dcus, etc.  `Build` compiles and then builds the output module (exe, dll, etc).  `Clean` deletes all the .dcus and other generated files from any previous build.  It's not a wild idea - it's in fact a *good* idea to clean regularly, especially before deployment builds, after version control updates (and before commits!), etc, to make sure that your codebase is still coherent and intact and that it's not just building with bad `.pas` files and old, but working, .dcus.

Comment: @J... If I interpret this correctly, the difference between 'clean' and 'build' would be that the first also removes .dcu files that do not 'belong' to the projects(s)? The build would recompile all those belonging to the project anyway.

Comment: @JanDoggen  No, clean doesn't build or compile anything.  It just deletes *all* .dcus (and other generated files) that the compiler would produce when building your project.  Build and compile will only re-compile those .dcus whose source .pas files the IDE is aware have changed since the last compile.  Any .pas files that the IDE *is not aware have changed*, and for whom compiled .dcus exist, will *not* be compiled in a normal build.  They will simply be linked into the .exe as-is at link-time.

Comment: This can be a problem if you have .pas files that are out of sync with your .dcus *and* the IDE is not aware that this is the case.  In this case your application or library will build with the existing .dcus and will not reflect the actual code in the .pas files.  A common time this happens, for example, is when you update a version control checkout.  Your .pas files may update but you will still have old .dcus.  Building will use the old .dcus and you may not be aware of a problem with the source changes until, at some point, you modify one of those source files and the .dcus recompile.